# Displaying Jquery data in html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This takes the text from a text file and displays it, refreshing every five seconds. I'd like the text to scroll across the screen announcement banner style. The marquee is just a placeholder, how do I go about doing this?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Raffle Winers</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.marquee.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
            body {
          margin: 10px;
          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }
        small {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .marquee, .marquee-with-options {
          width: 300px;
          overflow: hidden;
          border:1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var $mwo = $('.marquee-with-options');
            $('.marquee').marquee();
            $('.marquee-with-options').marquee({
                //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
                speed: 5000,
                //gap in pixels between the tickers
                gap: 50,
                //gap in pixels between the tickers
                delayBeforeStart: 0,
                //'left' or 'right'
                direction: 'left',
                //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
                duplicated: true,
                //on hover pause the marquee - using jQuery plugin https://github.com/tobia/Pause
                pauseOnHover: true
            });

            //pause and resume links
            $('.pause').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $mwo.trigger('pause');
            });
            $('.resume').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $mwo.trigger('resume');
            });
            //toggle
            $('.toggle').hover(function(e){
                $mwo.trigger('pause');
            },function(){
                $mwo.trigger('resume');
            })
            .click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(read,100);
    function read(){
    jQuery.get('rafflewinners.txt',function(data){$('#container').html(data);});
}
</script>

<div id="container"></div>


<div id="container" data-speed="2000" data-gap="30" data-direction="right" class='marquee'>#container</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Use a jQuery marquee plugin? Google it and you'll find a bunch.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for posting about the marquee plugin, it works well. One more thing, how can I make this work: <div>#container</div> instead of how I showed it above?

Comment: `<div id="container"></div>`

Comment: @Barmar <div id="container"></div> works well, but <div id="container" data-speed="10000" data-gap="30" data-direction="right" class='marquee'></div> with the marquee plugin doesn't work?

Comment: What's the URL of the plugin you're using?

Comment: http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jquerymarquee/

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Comment: @Barmar fixed small mistake it's there

Comment: You have two DIVs with the same ID, that's not allowed.

Comment: Okay, so now it's just this: <div id="container" data-speed="2000" data-gap="30" data-direction="right" class='marquee'></div>
It displays the text fine, but doesn't scroll. When it doesn't have that ID and has some text between the <div> tags, it scrolls and displays the text just fine. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marquee plugin stops working if the contents of the DIV are changed after it's initialized. You have to initiate it again.

```
function read(){
    jQuery.get('rafflewinners.txt',function(data){
        $('#container').html(data).marquee();
    });
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bCcq6/1/)